# Is there a way to create a StateFlow from a Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

Can I create a StateFlow from a Flow so that I can get the .value of it?  Is there a way to do it without using .collect?

Something like

```
val myStateFlow = StateFlow<MyDataType>(this.existingFlow)
```

So that later, when someone clicks a button, I can say what the last value of the flow is?

```
fun handleButton() {
  val lastValue = myStateFlow.value
  print(lastValue)
}
```

I would prefer not using collect, since I dont want the flow to flow until someone else decides to collect it.

Comment: [stateIn](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function called [stateIn](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html).

> Is there a way to do it without using .collect?
> I would prefer not using collect, since I dont want the flow to flow until someone else decides to collect it.

If you use the non-suspending overload of `stateIn`, the flow collection doesn't have to start right away, but you have to provide an initial value for the state (because this call cannot wait for the first value of the flow if it doesn't suspend).

In that case, you can play with the `started` argument to make the actual collection lazy, but note that accessing `myStateFlow.value` won't trigger the collection of the flow and will just return the initial value over and over. Only terminal flow operators (like `collect`) on the `StateFlow` will actually trigger the underlying flow collection, which is probably not what you want (but maybe it is!).

Note that you have to have a coroutine running to get the values from the initial flow and set the state accordingly if you want to access values via `myStateFlow.value`. This is actually what `stateIn` does by default: it starts a coroutine that collects the flow to set the `StateFlow`'s value - so it technically uses `collect`.